# SQL SELECT using custom field name (not ID) in WHERE

Tags: custom-fields, query, mysql

Forgive me if I missing something obvious, but I have a need to select channel entries from the EE database, but I want to select those entries based on a value assigned to one of my channels custom fields. In the `exp_channel_data` table though I have no guaranteed way of knowing which column that data might be in due to how EE adds columns to the table. It could be `field_id_27` or `field_id_123`. I could look in the admin, get the ID and then infer the column name, but that's clunky. Also, I'm trying to use this in a custom plug-in and I can't assume the ID will always be the same as I move the code from EE install to EE install. So what I want to know, and can't find, is what is the recommend method to build a SQL query in EE to be able to use a particular custom field in your WHERE clause?

To put it another way, if my custom field is named `my_cutom_field` what I want to do is be able to say:

`WHERE my_custom_field = 'some value'`

I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can prepare an array which would contain the custom field name and id like:

```
$fields = array();

$query = $ee()->db->query("SELECT exp_channel_fields.field_id, exp_channel_fields.field_name FROM exp_channel_fields
LEFT JOIN exp_channels ON exp_channel_fields.group_id=exp_channels.field_group 
WHERE exp_channels.channel_name='[CHANNEL NAME]'");

foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $fields[$row['field_name']] = 'field_id_'.$row['field_id'];
}
```

Now within the `WHERE` condition you can put like:
`WHERE $fields['my_custom_field '] = 'some value'`

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try working this method into my solution. What I still have never understood, and maybe this is a whole new question, is why Ellis choose this data model for the custom fields? I personally think I would have used custom field table with a relational table to map that data to the channel data

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `JOIN` on `exp_channel_fields` which contains the field metadata?